# Select a random button in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

So I have 9 buttons on my form , and when I press on a button I want to select one of the 9 buttons and change his text to - "random" . How can I do that in visual basic 2008/2010 ?

I was thinking to something like

```
 For Each buttons In Panel1.Controls
         If TypeName(buttons) = "Button" Then
               //select a random button and change his text to "random"
          End If
 Next buttons
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var buttons = from controls in this.Controls.OfType<Button>() select controls;

buttons.ElementAt(new Random().Next(buttons.Count())).Text = "random";
```

I have not used VB, so just did this in C#. May be same/very similar in VB.

Edit: To answer your comment try something like the following:

```
var buttons = (from controls in this.Controls.OfType<Button>() where !controls.Text.Equals("random") select controls);

if (buttons.Count() > 0)
{
    buttons.ElementAt(new Random().Next(buttons.Count())).Text = "random";
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I implement your code in Visual Basic and it works. But now what about if the random button is same . If button has already text "random" I want to search for another button and change his text to "new random"